# WiFi (2,4G) Antenna Isolation. Why 3 capcitors version does not work

Tags: signal, wifi, isolation, wave, smith-chart

I need to isolate the antenna from the WiFi transmitter. There are some solutions on the market but none suitable for my application.

So I have started some experiments.

1. 2x PCBs creating DIY capacitor (separated by the layer of Kapton tape)
   [image]
   [image]

Which effectively creates 9 capacitors (three on the signal line six on the shield. The shield ones are parallel connected in pairs)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKrdzf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And it works pretty well.
[image]

But I would like to use stock capacitors instead. The second board has 3 1pF capacitors in series on both sides (values on schematic are not correct)

[image]
[image]
[image]

But this version efficiently is a short circuit for this frequency signal.
[image]

When I reduce the number of capacitors to one it is much better.
[image]
[image]

Two capacitors behave much worse.
[image]

The length of the boars is 1/4 of the wave length in the copper.

The question. Why is the three (or two) capacitor version is almost blocking the signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trace impedances are not controlled or defined for each segment of path.

Ballpark figures

e.g. 1pF and 1nH (~2mm) wire can resonate @ 5 GHz, 3pF @ 2.85 GHz  This will affect your antenna S21 curve and S11 differently.

- unless you sweep over a wider range e.g. from 1 to 5 GHz you cannot see the magnitude of the problems with resonance. You may not be seeing high Q problems.

Using small tools or your fingertip with a neoprene glove to act as a small shield capacitance in pF over traces, so you can locate the sensitivity of interactive reactances.

- But a proper design would require better design tools to analyze the LC and loss tangent of substrate. (Maxwell, etc)
- GETEK Polyamide or equiv. or Teflon is required for PCB substrate for much lower loss tangent of S21.
- for floating antenna , you have not defined the insulation breakdown voltage or impedance reason for isolation at low frequency.
- 1pF at 2.4GHz is about -j4 ohms, but the path length adds about 0.3nH/mm for this aspect ratio and about 0.8 nH/mm for a skinny wire. (ballpark) so replacing a cap with a jumper won't work well.
- there is no ground plane under cap

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I need isolation 1.5kV for ATEX certification.

Comment: There is no ground plane under the cap as there is another track with 3 caps (they are on both sides of the PCB.

Comment: You can purchase 2.4Ghz atex antennas. Not cheap though. Or another option is to capacitively couple it through a glass window.

Comment: @Kartman I like the Borosilicate Glass idea, but it has a Dk of 4.6 and PU plastic film is only Dk of 3.6 and better loss tangent than Teflon and FAR better than FR4.  This makes the stripline element or patch antenna into a **microstrip sandwich**, which requires re-tuning.  But great idea.